# Focus the folders area in save dialogs

Tags: macos, shortcut

Is there a shortcut to focus the folders area in the save dialogs? I've found the followings shortcuts, but I would like to be able to just **focus the currently selected folder**.

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd> Changes focus to your Desktop

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd> Changes focus to your Applications directory

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>H</kbd> Changes focus to your Home directory

**Edit**: In other words, when the save dialog is open, you can press <kbd>tab</kbd> 8 times to focus the folders area. But I would like to know if there is a shortcut to get the same result quicker.

Comment: The currently selected folder **where**? In the Save dialog? In Finder?

Comment: @patrix I mean focus on the folders area of the save dialog (without redirecting to another folder)

Comment: In which app are you using the Save dialog?

Comment: @Buscar웃 In Firefox or Chrome for example

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no shortcut to do this, which is a shame. If you're trying to do it slightly quicker than pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> 8 times, you could hold <kbd>⇧</kbd> and press <kbd>tab</kbd> 5 times to get there in the other direction.

A somewhat more direct way is to use the third-party [Shortcat](https://shortcatapp.com/) utility (currently in free beta), which enables keyboard selection of graphics UI elements.

In the save dialog, you can trigger Shortcat (by default, <kbd>⇧-⌘-Space</kbd>) and then start typing the name of any folder that's visible in the folder list. As soon as the folder is highlighted (and no other UI elements are), press return. You can then navigate from there with the arrow keys.

Another built-in method that's so close, but yet so far, is to press <kbd>⌘-⇧-G</kbd>, then start typing the path of the folder you want. (Instead of <kbd>⌘-⇧-G</kbd>, you can also press <kbd>~</kbd> to start from your home directory, or <kbd>/</kbd> to start from the root.) While typing the path, you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> (or stop typing for a moment) to autocomplete folder names.

This would work quite well if the folder list automatically updated to show the directory corresponding to the path as you entered it, but unfortunately it doesn't update until you press <kbd>return</kbd>. Then if you want to continue navigating, you have to press <kbd>⌘-⇧-G</kbd> again to continue from where you left off.

A final possibility is to use a scripting/macro utility (like [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/), or [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/)) to make a global keyboard shortcut that presses <kbd>tab</kbd> 8 times for you. Seems a bit inelegant, though.